# enabling users to upload pictures from their harddrive in wysiwyg

Tags: 6, wysiwyg, files

I have wysiwyg module with IMCE enabled so I can browse the server of my site is located for pictures I can upload to add to my content. But the idea now is to have users that are bloggers to be able to upload pictures from their harddrive on to the site using a wysiwyg editor (in this case CKEditor).

Anyone experience with that and know how to do that or know of a good tutorial for this. When searching for an answer online I found info that explained how to add CCK fields to my content type but this is not what I want. I want bloggers to be able to choose where they put the pictures in text and how many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [WYSIWYG image upload module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_imageupload) successfully on my previous D6 sites. It has good documentation and a simple interface to do what you need.

Comment: It's out there! Thanks this totally did the job. Cheers!